# Opencart: getting value from textbox in tpl and pass into controller

Tags: php, textbox, opencart

How to get value from tpl. And pass into controller or library.

```
<input type="text" name="silverp" value="<?php echo $silverp; ?> "
placeholder="<?php echo $entry_sp; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
```

This is my textbox. Now i need to get this value in controller

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps -

1. Make a new function where you want to write the functionality to update the mass price of products in your controller.
2. Add the text input in the form and name it. Ex. "input-price"
3. Submit the form you created to the same function by adding its link to form action.
4. Get the value of text field in controller function by GET or POST request.

Ex.

`$_GET['input-price'] or for post $_POST['input-price']`